# How to remove top border

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to remove the top border or line on the top of the x axis.  I have set the x axis options like so:

```
     scales: {
     xAxes: [{
     gridLines: {
     drawBorder: false,
     },
```

but I still get the top border.

Comment: can you put an image? don't know what top border you talking about, or even better a fiddle example